# App disappears from Permission Set included with package

Tags: managed-package, app-development, permissions

We're working on our first Salesforce package, and recently switched from creating Beta packages to a Managed Package.

For some reason, the permission set that we're pushing loses the entry in Assigned Apps and I have no idea why.  Our custom tabs and objects come through just fine.  The App is installed as part of the package, and is visible to System Administrators.  I can create a new permission set on our Test Org that includes the package.

Early on in our testing and development, when we were pushing unmanaged or beta packages, I could have sworn that I saw this working correctly.

Am I missing some sort of overriding permissions issue, that prevents our Permission Set from granting access to our Application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, App and Tab visibility settings from packaged permission sets do not reflect in the destination org because Assigned Apps and tab visibility settings are **not** included in permission set components.

This is mentioned in the [Packaging Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_component_behavior.htm). You can vote up for this [Idea](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000ip4lAAA) on IdeaExchange so that this may get considered for a future release.

Comment: Just voted - c'mon SalesForce!

Comment: To be accurate - app and tab visibility is supported in permission sets but not in packaging. We're working on adding it in a future release to help alleviate this issue. I'm sorry for the delay supporting packaging.

Comment: @AdamTorman Any updates on a potential release? About to release a managed package to the AppExchange, and am trying to avoid all the post-installation instructions needed to just get the app running

Answer (score 9):

App and Tab visibility *can* be managed in a permission set as of Spring '12; however, neither are currently supported in packaging (and only tab settings are supported in the metadata API). As a result, assigned apps as a setting cannot be packaged although they can be manually configured on the permission set post installation.

Comment: I tried this with a managed package and it doesnt seem to allow me to edit the permission set post-install.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI (in case you're not already aware), at the time of writing Permission Sets are only available in **Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer** edition orgs.

Thus by using them you are making your package incompatible with Professional Edition.  This may not be an issue in your use case but thought I'd flag it just in case.

Comment: Then what's the recommended way to provide package users with an easy way to give their users access to features in the package?  We're new to the Salesforce platform, and got the impression that Permission Sets were the proper way to do it.

Comment: While this is great info, it isn't really an answer to the question; as such, I'd recommend using comments for similar messages in the future. ~B

Answer (score 2):

I observed the same issue while trying to package permission set for my managed package.

The packaging of permission sets is a little bit tricky :

> Permission Sets
>
> You can include permission sets as components in a package, with the following > 
>   permissions and access settings:
>
> ```
>    Custom object permissions
>    Custom field permissions
>    Apex class access
>    Visualforce page access>
> ```
>
> Note
>      Assigned apps and tab settings are not included in permission set components.

I hope SF will support the packaging of "apps & tabs" with them soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a close look at your connected app's metadata, you'll notice that when the Permitted Users changes from Admin approved to User approved, all the associated Permission Sets fall off that connected app's metadata (i.e. your `<permissionSetName>My Connected App User</permissionSetName>` metadata in that connected app is deleted)

The reason Permission Sets don't carry over is because of the root issue that the Permitted Users value is defaulting to User Approved when installing/upgrading a managed package.

I haven't seen this fix the managed package install issue, but there is new attribute in API v46.0 called `isAdminApproved`, whereby `true` mean's your Permitted Users setting is set to Admin approved.  See the [ConnectedApp Metadata Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) to see the new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure they are part of the included components for the managed package.

If you can create the `permission set`, your org is not in an addition that doesn't allow `fieldsets`, so that's probably not the problem.

Comment: The App is definitely part of the package -- System Administrators in the Test Org have access to it, and I can add it to a new permission set in the Test Org.